# How do use top select row to define a range, let's say between 40,000 - 45000?

Tags: sql, select, range, row

```
SELECT TOP (1000) [DBName]
      ,[TableName]
      ,[Reportdate]
      ,[ActionID]
      ,[Records]
      ,[DateCreated]
  FROM [PXYZ_database].[dbo].[SystemData]
```

So from the above query above, I want to make it to select row range from 44000 and 45000. I tried to write the query this way, but so far it's very complicated.

```
SELECT * FROM table limit 100 [DBName]
      ,[TableName]
      ,[Reportdate]
      ,[ActionID]
      ,[Records]
      ,[DateCreated]

  FROM [PXYZ_database].[dbo].[SystemData]
```

But I'm receiving error, is my syntax wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use an `order by` clause with an `offset` option:

```
  SELECT [DBName]
        ,[TableName]
        ,[Reportdate]
        ,[ActionID]
        ,[Records]
        ,[DateCreated]
    FROM [PXYZ_database].[dbo].[SystemData]
ORDER BY [DBName] OFFSET 44000  ROWS FETCH NEXT 1000 ROWS ONLY
```